# Choose the right proof pattern

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I am a bit confused with the following problem.

Let's say, there is a group of 10 people and the task is to prove that at least one of them has the height less or equal to the average height of the group.

I tried to use a proof by contradiction as follows:
A height of each person in the group is greater than average (which is obviously false) and therefore it is a contradiction, but not 100% sure if it is the right way to solve this problem.

Could anyone advise me how to prove it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Assume everyone has height strictly less than the average. Then the average $A=(h_1+…+h_n)/n<$nA/n=A$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

We have the formula $$ A = \frac {x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}$$

Now if for each $n$ we have $x_n>A$, we will get
$$A = \frac {x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}> \frac {nA}{n}=A$$

That is $A>A$ which we do not accept.

Thus for at least one n, we have to have $x_n\le A$